# The birthday puzzles

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Here is a couple of birthday puzzles based some time in the future:

**Puzzle 1**

```
Your birthday was yesterday at exactly 12pm (noon). Today is 12pm the next day. 
It is now 365 days till your next birthday.
```

> How many hours until your next birthday from 12pm yesterday and why?

**Puzzle 2**

```
Your birthday was today at 11:59am. 
It is now 364 days until your birthday.
```

> What day this year is this describing and why? (Answer in dd/mm/yyyy format)

Comment: Did my birthday begin or end at the times given? Are we talking about a birth instant? Or,,, are those considerations all part of the puzzle?

Comment: Am I using jewish calendar coz it has 364 days.

Comment: @manshu The Hebrew calendar has 353-355 days, or 383-385 with Adar I (the leap month)...

Answer (score 2):

**Puzzle 1 solution**

> From 12:00 noon on your birthday yesterday, it will be $366*24=8,784$ hours until your next birthday.

Why?

> There's a leap year February 29 between this birthday and your next one, giving you an extra day between birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

**Puzzle 2 Solution**

His/Her birthday is on

> Any date. But there should not be any 29th February between those birthdays.

**The Reason**

> If I celebrate my first birthday in Honolulu and next birthday in Kiritimati then I can say that I waited for 364 days for my second birthday because the difference in their time zones is 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

**Puzzle 1**

> 8772 hours.

Reasoning:

> There's a leap day before your next birthday, so it's 366 days. However, we're counting from noon, which means it's only 12 hours until the next day rather than 24.

**Puzzle 2**

> 07/11/2016

Reasoning:

> You're located in [Troll Station, Antarctica](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/antarctica/troll). By 11:59am, the clocks have already rolled back. You get the benefit of the roll forward (1 hour), but when it's your birthday again (00:00 on 07/11/2017) the clocks won't change until 02:00.
>  Normally at 11:59am it would be 364 days, 12 hours and 1 minute until your next birthday. However, because you're between clocks rolling back, you get 364 days, 11 hours and 1 minute, which we can round down to 364 days!

Comment: The UK clocks change would work on any day from 25-31 October, 2020, since the change is 31/10/2021. That's not this year, though.